# move image in text area in flex

Tags: apache-flex, image, flex3, textarea

[alt text http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/1183/tedit.jpg](http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/1183/tedit.jpg)

Hi Guys,

I am trying to make a text editor in Flex. 
i can move image on mouse click. 
Problem is it moves with the key up or down handler. But it moves out of text area after the last line in textarea. And it also doesn't move with scroll.

Pls give suggestions for these problems.

Thanks.

Regards,
Shivang

Answer (score 0):

You may want to increase the white space of your 'text editor'. Just have numbers up till person entered text. That way when you move to the bottom you are not moving outside of the textArea.

would need more example of what is going wrong with the key up or down handler. What events are you trying to capture? How are you dragging the image?

good luck.